# How to calculate the hypothesis testing of lognormal distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference, lognormal-distribution

I have a sample of observations which is right-skewed and taking the natural logarithm brings it close to a normal distribution, e.g. $Y=\log X$, and $Y$ follows a normal distribution.

I want to test if $\mu_X = 30$ so the null hypothesis is $H_0:\mu_X = 30$ against the alternative hypothesis  $\mu_X > 30$.

I am stuck with it since $X$ is lognormal but not normal. So, how can I conduct this hypothesis test?

Comment: What do you mean by "test if X = 30" ?

Comment: I want to know if the mean is 30.

Comment: note that $X=30$ is different from $\mu_X = 30$;

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I mean /mu=30, but X does follow normal distribution, so can I convert it into /mu_y = ln(30)?

Comment: No, not really, in general $E(\log X)\neq \log(EX)$. But you can test $\mu_X=30$, even if $X$ is not normal, by the bootstrap method.

Comment: When $Y$ has a Normal distribution with mean $\mu_Y$ and standard deviation $\sigma_Y,$ the mean of $X$ is $\mu_X = \exp(\mu_Y + \sigma_Y^2/2).$  Thus, to test whether $\mu_X = 30$ you will test the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_Y + \sigma_Y^2/2 = \log(30).$  How you do that depends on whether you assume a value for $\sigma_Y$ or not and on how much data you have (because applying, say, Maximum Likelihood or a bootstrap to small datasets is risky in this setting).  There exist several tests in the literature, each with its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Hi, Whuber. I have 51 observations in my dataset. Is it large enough? Thank you for answering.

Comment: There's no way to tell, because it depends also on the value of $\sigma_Y.$

Comment: If you're willing to test the median rather than the mean, you should consider using something like a signed rank test, which is valid for any distribution.